# Cannot connect hibernate with MySql Azure database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, azure

I have a MySQL database on Azure. On Netbeans, I have a web project with Hibernate. I've generated the hibernate.cfg and was OK. Then, I tried to generate reveng.xml, but after a minute it shows a error message: 'Unable to establish a connection to the database with the selected Hibernate configuration file . Check the details of the connection in hibernate.cfg.xml'.
When I go to Azure web, it shows that I've used all my available connections (my azure account allows only 4 mysql connections) but I think that I only use 1 connection when I try to generate reveng file.

Comment: Would you please add your hibernate.cfg.xml and some code details..

Comment: @SkyWalker [Here](http://pastebin.com/vHGitgJH) is the hibernate config. Actually, it's the only file in my project. I'm using Hibernate 4.3. Netbeans 8.0.2.

Comment: Can you remove all 'hibernate." between '<property>' and '</property>' and try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kind of configuration files for Hibernate include XML configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml` and Properties configuration file `hibernate.properties`.

If you want to configure the Hibernate session factory using XML file `hibernate.cfg.xml`, the prefix `hibernate.` is not needed, but need for the `hibernate.properties` file.

More details for XML configuration file, please see the section [`XML configuration file`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-xmlconfig) of the offical document.